# android-info.txt file is not generated while building android source

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I have run the following commands -

1. I cleaned up the existing build using command - make clean
2. source build/envsetup.sh OR . build/envsetup.sh
3. lunch full_crespo-userdebug
4. make -j4 (make fastboot adb)
5. adb reboot bootloader
6. fastboot -w flashall

I did these in my MAC OSX 10.9.1 and for the phone Nexus S (crespo). I have no clue why it is not generating the android-info.txt file. Every time I run fastboot command, it says it's missing. However, I have also set up the path ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT in my .bash_profile file. Still no luck. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Can you copy paste the error message given by fastboot -w flashall? Does it generate android-info.txt for other builds (i.e. mako) or is this specific to crespo?

Comment: Eishitas-MacBook-Pro:OS fze013$ fastboot flashall -w
error: could not load android-info.txt

--- This is what I get

Comment: Try putting an android-info.txt file in out/target/product/CRESPOS_BUILD_DIR and put the line: require board=herring in it. Should look like this: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/android-device-crespo/blob/master/board-info.txt but with just the first line.

Comment: I guess that won't be very helpful since along with the android-info.txt file it's not also generating the .img files. I need all of them. Thanks for your help :).